# How to include custom doc-comment elements in Sandcastle Help File?

Tags: c#, sandcastle

In C# if I have a method that I add XML documenting, the following will be generated by default:

```
/// <summary>
/// Does something
/// </summary>
public string SomeValue { get; set; }
```

I want to add my own doc-comment as follows below which is just fine in VS.NET build:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <usage>Required</usage>
public string SomeValue { get; set; }
```

The problem is I do not see the new `<usage>` comment values displayed on my output `.chm` file. I'm pretty new to using Sandcastle so it might be something easy I'm missing, but I didn't see what I was looking for in the documentation.

Does anyone know how to incorporate the `<usage>` value in my output help file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Supporting Custom tags in Sandcastle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sandcastle/archive/2006/11/22/supporting-custom-tags-in-sandcastle.aspx?Redirected=true) is an old article, but might still be relevant or at least point you in the right direction.