# Chm or html documentation from an user defined xml

Tags: c#, html, xml, chm

I am writing a command line utility. This utility has a set of components which exposes commands. e.g. A component 'FileIO' will expose commands to copy, delete files etc.
This works on a custom xml as below :

```
<Component>
    <Description> This component exposes commands for file i/o. </Description>
    <Name>FileIO</Name>
    <Commands>
        <Command>
            <Name>Copy</Name>
            <Options>
                <Option>
                    <Name>S<Name>
                    <Type>String<Type>
                    <Description>Source file path to be copied from</Description>
                <Option>
                <Option>
                    <Name>D<Name>
                    <Type>String<Type>
                    <Description>Target path to copy a file</Description>
                <Option>
            </Options>
        </Command>
        <Command>
            <Name>Delete</Name>
            <Options>
                <Option>
                    <Name>S<Name>
                    <Description>Path of a file to be deleted</Description>
                    <Type>String<Type>
                <Option>
            </Options>
        </Command>
    </Commands>
</Component>
```

Based on this xml I use commands as below:

```
Root>cd FileIO
Root\FileIO>Copy -S "C:\\Source.txt" -D "D:\\Target.txt"
```

Now, I am trying to generate document or a help file (html or chm) from this xml file. I would like to have chm or html generated in msdn style where I can add some code snippets and the usage of the command.

e.g

```
Copy
Usage : Copy -S [Value] -D [Value]
        -S : Source file path to be copied from
        -D : Target path to copy a file 
Snippet:
    Root>cd FileIO
    Root\FileIO>Copy -S "C:\\Source.txt" -D "D:\\Target.txt"
```

How do I generate, documentation from this xml file? I would prefer to generate this documentation at run time using C#.

Comment: What's about using Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013972/embedding-images-in-chm-help-file-with-sandcastles

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486401/how-to-include-custom-doc-comment-elements-in-sandcastle-help-file

Comment: Transform the XML to generate html and the XML toc and index, and compile it with a CHM compiler like MS workshop.